# jQuery .fadeOut() then .show(); not working with keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

After keyup, I want the numbers to disappear so I tried .fadeOut() in the if, and .show() on the else.  The problem is that they don't show back up after they fade out.

```
    $('input').keyup(function() {
filter(this);

});

function filter(element) {
var value = $(element).val();

$("#sortable > li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
        $(".number").fadeOut();
        $(".numberstwo").fadeOut();

        // $('#sortable').addClass("disable");
       // $("#sortable").draggable('disable');

    } else {
        $(this).hide();
        $(".number").show();
        $(".numberstwo").show();         
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because fadeOut uses css opacity, while show uses css display.

Basically, when you do do `.fadeOut()`, you are reducing the opacity of the element to 0, and then when you call `.show()`, nothing happens because it's trying to set the display property to what it already is... the opacity is unaffected, and stays at 0.

You will want to use `.fadeIn()` to bring your element back into view.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

On the flip side of that, `.show()` should be paired with `.hide()` which sets display to 'none'.

Comment: I should definitely ask another question, but quickly looking at it - do you know why $("#sortable").draggable('disable'); isn't working?

Comment: Hmm, I'd need to see a bit more context to be able to tell you that. Making a new question is probably a good idea.

Comment: [@BlakeMann](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2414515/blake-mann) This is not exactly correct: while it is true that the `fadeOut` operates on `opacity`, it is important to notice that at the end of the animation, the `display` property is set to `none` and then `opacity` is restored to the original value.